# django.contrib.auth.views LogoutView not working

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am using latest version of django and I want to create a LogoutView using builtin system. But this is giving error when I try to run the server, and not working LogoutView.

[image: error image]

Below is the urls.py code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('food/',include('food.urls')),

    path('register/',user_views.register,name='register'),

    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'),name='logout'),

]
```

When I checked, I found that the error is :

```
HTTP error code 405 stands for "Method Not Allowed."  Django's LogoutView, the expected method for logout is typically POST but this is getting in terminal:

"GET /logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
Method Not Allowed (GET): /logout/
Method Not Allowed: /logout/
```

Comment: Can you give your logout.html? I guess your logout form method using get method.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I found that the get method is deprecated for LogoutView from Nov 2023.
The solution is explained in the link below.

[Deprecation of the GET method for LogoutView](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/deprecation-of-get-method-for-logoutview/25533)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Replace the: `<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>` (in the .html file) with:

```
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you started writing your website, you created a project using the command `django-admin startproject projectname`. This created a directory named projectname with files in it. One of such files is your urls.py.

Also, you are expected to create an app using the command `python manage.py startapp appname` because a django project is made up of apps. This creates the app directory which contains your models, views, etc. Each app is expected to have its own urls.py so you have to create one.

From what you presented, you are mixing up your project level urls.py with your app urls.py. Your project level urls.py is located in the directory that contains your project and should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('food/',include('food.urls')), # url pattern to include food app
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), # url pattern to include users app
]
```

I'm assuming your app name is users since you're using default Django's user auth. I'm also guessing you've defined it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py` by adding 'users' to the list. Create a file named urls.py in the users app directory and enter the following:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # Include default auth urls.
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/',user_views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

Please verify that the paths you included in your urls.py are without errors. If so, it should work now. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/overview/).

Answer (score 0):

No longer supported in Django 5 per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#features-removed-in-5-0 as Amin also wrote.

Answer (score 0):

After November 2023, the implementation for **logout** should as below:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>
```